# Double LinkedList and remove

Tags: java

I'm working on Doubly Linked Lists and one of the method i have to create is remove method which removes ALL instances of targetData from the list and I must remove the elements by performing a single traversal over the list. however, my method doesn't remove all the instance and i couldn't figure out why
this is my method

Comment: I presume that this is a homework exercise?  (Otherwise, you should just be using a container-class ...)  Well, one very handy "trick" with doubly-linked lists is to initialize the list to always contain one **"dummy"** entry, which is initially linked to itself.  This dummy, or anchor, entry is always ignored during traversal, and of course cannot be removed.  What this buys you is that "the code for inserting or removing a node is always the same, because there is always at least one node (the dummy ...) on the list.

Answer (score -1):

Use recursion:

```
removeNode(node);
{
    if(node.next==null){
        node.pre=null;
        node=null;
    }else{
        removeNode(node.next);
        node.next=null;
        node.pre=null;
        node=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not allowed to used recursion @Dipak Prajapati

Comment: @Robert there is nothing complicated in this code to explain. and haylu please mention all the condition in Question, don't mention it after we provide you solution.

Comment: It's not complicated to you, but if it was clear to the thread starter, he wouldn't have had to ask.